# Make a drive always available offline

Tags: windows, group-policy, offline-files

I have configured a drive to be available offline. This drive maps to my user's home drive. The only setting that I cannot figure out is how to automatically select the "Always available offline" option on the drive at each domain user's computer. Is there a command or PowerShell cmdlet I can run to do this? Or perhaps using WMI?

Comment: i found this powershell script  $o = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$o.Namespace("Z:\").Self.verbs() |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Always &available offline' } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.DoIt() } here [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9fc4fe46-1bc5-4e58-9eb8-a01b7c83e135/script-always-available-offline-for-subfolder-of-share-on-windows-7-x64-client?forum=ITCG)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Administratively assigned offline files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978568.aspx) group policy setting to make the desired location always available offline as follows:

1. In Group Policy editor, navigate to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files`
2. Enable the **Specify administratively assigned offline files** policy
3. Configure the policy by clicking **Show...** and in the **Value name** column specify the fully qualified UNC path to the folder to always make available offline (e.g. `\\Server\Share\%USERNAME%`). Leave the **Value** field blank.
   **Note:** According to this [SpiceWorks thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/317401-home-drive-available-offline) you should be able to use environment variables when specifying the UNC path name.